# JAXB in java 6 not prefixing the correct namespace prefix in marshalled XML file

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, prefix

I have a schema with following attributes in schema element:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abc="http://abc.example.com" targetNamespace="http://abc.example.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

I could compile it and get java classes. Using these classes, I filled in data in an object and marshalled it to get an XML file.

But the XML elements in this marshalled file is not having the prefix "abc".

I tweaked a little using XMLStreamWriter.setPrefix while marshalling, and I could get the XML file with all elements prefixed as "abc".

Now when I try to unmarshall the same XML file, it throws error saying :

[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "abc" for element "abc:Name" is not bound.]

Please help me in how to let JAXB know that abc is correct prefix.

Thank You
Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the prefix is meaningless. All it does is make a connection between a namespace and the tags that belong to that namespace. Whether the prefix is *abc* or *namespace01* or there is no prefix because the default namespace is used doesn't matter. As far as I know you can't force the usage of a prefix or the specific name of a prefix in JAXB.

Comment: thanks musiKk, now I understand it.

But if we want to use our own defined prefix, we can use JAXB RI which contains NamespacePrefixMapper along with JAXB from Java 6. [include JAXB RI in classpath].

marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespaceMapper());

Comment: @pradeep: Nice. Even though you make yourself dependent on a specific implementation it's good to know.

Comment: Don't totally agree on the "meaningless" part. It may be "meaningless" from a technical point of view. But assume that e.g. - in any way - a human will see or work with the XML, it might be important to be able to set the namespace prefixes in a meaningful way...

Answer (score 2):

In the article below I demonstrate how this can be achieved using `NamespacePrefixMapper` from the JAXB RI, and the `@XmlSchema` annotation with [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html