# Configure namespace prefix in JAXB bindings file

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces, jaxb2

I generate Java files from an XSD using namespaces. When the corresponding Java objects are serialized to XML the namespaces prefixes are `ns1`, `ns2` ... There seems to be three ways [to control the prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1982977/2107731):

1. If using Oracle's Java one can add an [implementation of the internal class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983172/2107731) `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper` to the marshaller.
2. If the file `package-info.java` is under your control then you can add [the annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33343694/2107731) `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs` to it. This does not work when the Java files are generated from a XSD.
3. You can add a [third party tool](https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Namespace-prefix) and configure the `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs` annotation in the JAXB binding file.

The 3rd option is non standard and its last version is from 2012. Is there an equivalent standard option available in the meantime, e.g. an element or attribute in the standard namespaces `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb` or `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc`?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040682/jaxb-in-java-6-not-prefixing-the-correct-namespace-prefix-in-marshalled-xml-file/4041337

Answer (score -3):

There are newest version of 3rd option [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin)

Comment: Thank you for the information. This option still relies on Maven. However, I'm looking for an element or attribute in the standard namespaces `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb` or `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc`. Moreover the Maven plugin still depends on the extension `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.jaxb2-namespace-prefix` which is from 2012.

Comment: the serialized xml already has namespaces. It is the namespace **prefix** I want to configure.